# Setup jndi for jboss

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss, jndi

I just got done setting up a little template project using spring, hibernate, and jboss. I thought I had a good basic template until I got into work today, and learned about connection pooling and JNDI. I understand the concept of connection pooling, but I have no idea where to get started with config files, or server configuration, or even custom java files. I went to my boss today to ask him about it, and he started talking about the mysql-ds.xml file which I saw in one of the "example" folders located in the jboss application server folder. I also noticed that he wrote a custom datasourcefactory java file which reads a config file and depending on if one of the config elements says JNDI or C3P0, it will create a connection from it. I tried to google around, but I can't find a good example on how to get this setup.

Here is my current application-context file that creates the hibernate sessions and datasource

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="examplePassword" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mySessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.example.domain.administrative.user.User</value>
                <value>com.example.domain.administrative.role.Role</value>
                <value>com.example.domain.administrative.team.Team</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

I added values to the mysql-ds.xml file and put it in my deploy folder. I commented out the  ...  in the applicationContext file. I started the server, and it seems to be picking up the connection from the mysql-ds.xml file automatically, but I am getting an exception on startup now:

```
19:18:34,782 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Instantiated: name=jboss.jca:name=jdbc/exampleDs,service=ManagedConnectionFactory state=Described mode=Manual requiredState=Configured: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/transaction/xa/XAResource"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:926) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:297) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295) [:1.6.0_43]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249) [:1.6.0_43]
    at org.jboss.classloader.plugins.loader.ClassLoaderToLoaderAdapter.loadClass(ClassLoaderToLoaderAdapter.java:184) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.ClassLoaderDomain.loadClassFromParent(ClassLoaderDomain.java:607) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.ClassLoaderDomain.loadClassBefore(ClassLoaderDomain.java:562) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:269) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1172) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2398) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2708) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1659) [:1.6.0_43]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.instantiate(MBeanServerImpl.java:1244) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.instantiate(MBeanServerImpl.java:288) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceCreator.installPlainMBean(ServiceCreator.java:217) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceCreator.install(ServiceCreator.java:133) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.InstantiateAction.installAction(InstantiateAction.java:73) [:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.InstantiateAction.installAction(InstantiateAction.java:46) [:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:301) [:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:671) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.install(ServiceController.java:257) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:93) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:49) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:63) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_43]

19:18:34,794 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfs:///C:/Development/JBoss/example-jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/mysql-ds.xml state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying: jboss.jca:service=ManagedConnectionFactory,name=jdbc/exampleDs
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:125) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:49) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:63) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_43]
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/transaction/xa/XAResource"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:926) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:297) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295) [:1.6.0_43]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249) [:1.6.0_43]
    at org.jboss.classloader.plugins.loader.ClassLoaderToLoaderAdapter.loadClass(ClassLoaderToLoaderAdapter.java:184) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.ClassLoaderDomain.loadClassFromParent(ClassLoaderDomain.java:607) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.ClassLoaderDomain.loadClassBefore(ClassLoaderDomain.java:562) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:269) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1172) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2398) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2708) [:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1659) [:1.6.0_43]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.instantiate(MBeanServerImpl.java:1244) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.instantiate(MBeanServerImpl.java:288) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceCreator.installPlainMBean(ServiceCreator.java:217) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceCreator.install(ServiceCreator.java:133) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.InstantiateAction.installAction(InstantiateAction.java:73) [:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.InstantiateAction.installAction(InstantiateAction.java:46) [:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:301) [:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:671) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.install(ServiceController.java:257) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:93) [:6.1.0.Final]
    ... 48 more

19:18:34,860 INFO  [xnio] XNIO Version 2.1.0.CR2
19:18:34,868 INFO  [nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 2.1.0.CR2
19:18:35,041 INFO  [remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.1.0.Beta2
19:18:35,105 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/
19:18:35,162 INFO  [config] Initializing Mojarra 2.0.3 ( b05) for context ''
19:18:36,572 INFO  [service] Removing bootstrap log handlers
19:18:36,616 ERROR [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Failed to load profile:: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfs:///C:/Development/JBoss/example-jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/mysql-ds.xml" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/transaction/xa/XAResource"

    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1228) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:905) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.checkComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:87) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.checkAllComplete(ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.java:107) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:135) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_43]

19:18:36,633 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080
19:18:36,640 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8009
19:18:36,640 INFO  [org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer] JBossAS [6.1.0.Final "Neo"] Started in 24s:775ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I have always found working examples one of the best ways to learn.  You should check out the [JDF Quickstarts](http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/get-started/). There is a [Spring Quickstart](https://github.com/jboss-jdf/jboss-as-quickstart/tree/master/kitchensink-spring) too.

Answer (score 0):

For setting up the data source check out the [DataSource configuration wiki page](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7). You need to deploy the MySQL driver has a module because [#jdbcCompliant](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62038) returns `false`. To look it up use

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS"/>
```

(don't forget to register the jee namespace in the xml).

You don't need to do any connection pooling, JBoss does this for you automatically. As for transactions all you have to do is

```
<tx:jta-transaction-manager  />
```

(again don't forget to register the tx namespace in the xml).

Als always do not pack any API (JPA, JTA, …) or Hibernate JARs into your application.